# How can I create an expansion gap for a floating floor around an impermanent column?

Tags: flooring

I'm doing a floating floor install in the basement ([Uniclic cork planks](https://www.cancork.com/installation-of-forna-cork-floating-floors/)) and there is usual requirement of 1/2 inch gap all around so the floor can expand and move.

One complication I have is a Swedish ladder that is mounted between floor and ceiling in a corner, but away from walls. It is held in place by compression, so it effectively serves as a column transferring weight from joists in the ceiling down to the concrete floor.

Instructions for the flooring specify that things like kitchen cabinetry must not sit directly on the floor lest they pin it down too much.

Obviously I need to maintain expansion gap around the ladder somehow. The problem is the ladder is really removable, and if we ever move, we'll likely take it with us or new owner might want it removed, which would ideally leave the floor in a good state.

So far I'm thinking of laying the floor, then effectively cutting an expansion channel around ladder posts and covering it by hardwood T bar, like I would do any other same height transition. This will pin down floor section directly under the ladder, but would let the rest of the floor move freely.

In the absence of the ladder this would leave a square transition with slightly dented piece of flooring in the middle and maybe lead somebody to believe there is a hatch to an underground bunker underneath.

Are there better options?

EDIT:
Another option is to simply let the ladder pin the floor down in that one spot and let it expand all around. Are single fixed points allowed for floating floors?

Comment: Can you reduce the mount pressure of the rack and use anchors in the ceiling for security? I'd try to avoid this whole problem in the first place.

Comment: I think I would have to eliminate the pressure completely and hang the ladder, otherwise its base would move with the floor and get out of plumb (it is not designed for suspension anyway).

Comment: Your floor isn't going to move so far as to create a visual slope in the thing. :P All I'm saying is _reduce_ compression to something akin to a table leg.

Comment: Who knows, they insist on half an inch on all sides! :)

Comment: I just read that under the Installation section. I think there are typos there. 0.4 inches per meter of room width could easily be over an inch. Hogwash. 1mm is _0.04_ inches!

Comment: "so it effectively serves as a column transferring weight from joists in the ceiling down to the concrete floor" is it part of the framing strucure? Then it cannot be removed. If you own the place, make it nice for yourself. Your proposal is fine, and you could even put it on a 1 or 2 inch pedestal to not suggest it's a hatch. Or build a bunker underneath.

Comment: No, it is not a (necessary) part of the structure, but it presses down on the floor with the weight of the ceiling above, as much as I can extend it anyway. Bunker is unfortunately out of budget...

Comment: Good catch on the 1 mm per m, I think they mean 0.4 inch per 32.8 f, which is also the maximum run without expansion gap they specify just above, weird...